# Max heap conversion

Tags: binary-trees, heaps

In the binary tree shown below, which of the following trees is created after 
conversion into a (max) heap?

[image]

There are 4 anwsers to choose :

[image]

By definition, a max heap is a complete binary tree in which the value in **each internal node is greater than or equal to the values in the children of that node.**, so `a`, `c`, `d` are all correct, but there is only one correct anwser!

What am i missing here ?

Comment: Other than the typo, a very nice question. Option b with the typo corrected is the one you want. The key here is to move each node into its place, starting within the smaller sub-tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo in your options. In option (b) the root should be 16 not 1. The tree thus formed is the correct answer.

To get it from your original tree do this

> for i = floor(Array.Length/2) down to the first element: 
>       Max-Heapify(Array,i)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, option B is the correct one indeed, but what I don't get is, the others also satisfy the condition `each internal node is greater than or equal to the values in the children of that node` ? Why are they wrong?

Comment: They do but they havent been converted from the given tree.

Comment: ahh, I misread the question again! Thanks!